# Updating MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, updating

```
<?php

    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username=""; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="hsp_property"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="project_directory"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    //Get values from form
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $hospital = $_POST['hospital'];
    $project = $_POST['project'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $da_status = $_POST['da_status'];
    $pm = $_POST['pm'];
    $budgett = $_POST['budgett'];
    $budgetat = $_POST['budgetat'];
    $pdapproval = $_POST['pdapproval'];
    $pdcs = $_POST['pdcs'];
    $pdcd = $_POST['pdcd'];
    $pdcf = $_POST['pdcf'];
    $pnm = $_POST['pnm'];
    $prm = $_POST['prm'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    // update data in mysql database 
    $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET Hospital='$hospital', Project='$project', State='$state',Project_Status='$status',DA_Status='$da_status',Project_Manager='$pm',Budget_Total='$budgett',Budget_Approved='$budgetat',Project_Approval_Dates='$pdapproval',Project_Contstruction_Dates='$pdcs',Project_Contract_Dates='$pdcd',Project_Current_Dates='$pdcf',Program_Next_Milestone='$pnm',Program_Milestone='$prm',Comments='$comments' WHERE id='$id'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated. 
    if ($result) {
        header ('Location: ../project_directory.php');
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error';
    }

?>
```

The above is some code to update a MySQL db, i'm running WAMP to test the website before I'll upload.

I've been using the phpeasysteps tutorial as php and mysql is new to me. It's been working all ok until now.

Would love to know what i'm doing wrong, the PhpEasySteps tutorial might be a tad old as i've had to update a few elements of the initial code to get it to work..

Comment: What errors are you getting/expected results?

Comment: Nothing ... other than the echo 'Error' message!

Comment: Is your `id` column set to AUTO_INCREMENT? If not, then you're declaring `$id=$_POST['id'];` but not using it in your UPDATE and using it in your WHERE.

Comment: Another thing you can try is follow this example and do the same with the others `Hospital='" . $hospital . "'`

Comment: add and "or die" to see what the sql error is...

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: I've fixed the issue, after searching online and changing the echo 'Error' to Echo mysql_error() it couldn't find a column from the db.

Comment: That was going to be my next question actually. (if column(s) existed)

Comment: Thanks Fred -ii- and all who helped!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `echo 'Error';` with `echo mysql_error();` to see why you didn't get a result and then slap yourself for misspelling a column name or something most likely easily overlooked.  If you still can't figure it out, post the error.  And if you go that far, post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE project_directory`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$link_identifier` to your `mysql_select_db`  database selection,

Syntax:  `bool mysql_select_db ( string $database_name [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`

```
 $link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
 mysql_select_db("$db_name", $link)or die("cannot select DB");
```

You can use `mysql_error();` function to find the mysql related errors.